# TinyGPS++ isn't being updated or SoftwareSerial isn't reading

Tags: gps, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm trying to read the GPS data on an Arduino Uno from a Neo-6M module and print it on a LCD display. However, no variable is being changed by the read function. This could either be because of an incorrect reading of the `gps` variable or a wrong use of the `SoftwareSerial` library.

Here's the code:

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <splash.h>

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

Adafruit_SSD1306 display;  // Create display
SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(4,3);//rx,tx
float lati=0,longi=0;
float sat=0;
TinyGPSPlus gps; // create gps object 



void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  gpsSerial.begin(9600); // connect gps sensor 
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);  // Initialize display with the I2C address of 0x3C
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  display.clearDisplay();


    gps.encode(gpsSerial.read());
    display.setCursor(80,3);
    display.print("R");


  //if(gps.location.isUpdated())
  {
    lati = gps.location.lat();
    longi = gps.location.lng();
    sat = gps.satellites.value();
    display.setCursor(100,3);
    display.print("U");
  }

  display.setCursor(20,20);
  display.print(lati);
  display.setCursor(20,40);
  display.print(longi);
  display.setCursor(100,40);
  display.print(sat);
  display.drawRect(0,0,127,63,WHITE);
  display.display();
}
```

EDIT: The data coming from gpsSerial is a series of -1
EDIT 2: Swapping `SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(4,3);` to `SoftwareSerial gpsSerial(4,3);` makes it output a series of ints. However, encoding it with `gps.encode(gpsSerial.read())` still doesn't update the data.

Comment: no prints to Serial? why not use it for debug prints or connect the gps to it?

Comment: I'm powering the arduino with a battery to be able to go outside to test the reception, so I'm printing the information on the screen to read it as it's collected

Comment: then connect the module to Serial and don't use SoftwareSerial

Comment: I don't have a serial to miniUSB cable

Comment: pins RX and TX. 0 and 1.

Comment: did you connect RX to TX?

Comment: I tried rewriting the sketch to read data through the serial monitor and I tried swapping pins in every possible configuration, but i'm still getting the same problem. EDIT: I'm currently reading the direct gpsSerial.read() and it's a neverending series of -1s

Comment: read returns -1 if no data is available